# Need to show static directory located in root of WP install

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks

I'm trying to navigate to a directory (/mobileapp/) containing a static mobile web app, located in the root of my WP install.

My problem is that when I try going to the url (http://dawsondental.ca/mobileapp/  <--the live site if you want to check it out) I get the usual WP 404 Not Found page.

I tried creating an .htaccess file within the /mobileapp/ directory with the following:

```
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    #Disable rewriting
    RewriteEngine Off

    </IfModule>
```

But it's still not working. Maybe the WP permalink rewrite conditions are still taking over? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Move the `WordPress/MobileApp` directory out of *WordPress* to your *Web Root* folder (say, `/public_html` or `/www`). Then try accessing it as `http://dawsondental.ca/mobileapp/`.

Comment: I should add that this particular site/WP install is under a domain alias (in it's own directory, eg. public_html/dawsondental.ca/*WP-root*), so I believe putting /mobileapp/ in /public_html/ will remove it from that particular domain, right?

Comment: Create a simple `test.html` and place it at `/public_html`. If you are able to access it from `dawsondental.ca/test.html` you're set. If not, you need to look up other config files set up for your domain. Check for any other `.htaccess` files; inside web root, for example.